# Does the nix build daemon keep the build log?

Tags: nix, nixos

Sometime when running `nix-build` and `nixos-rebuild` I found easy-to-fix problems (like deprecated warnings or redundant imports) and I thought "Interesting, I might be able to fix that in my free time".

I know I could redirect the build log to a file but I keep forgetting to do it until I see the warning again.

Question: Does the nix build daemon save the build log somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

You can enable `build-cache-failures` in your `nix.conf` and then use a combination of

```
nix-store --query-failed-paths
```

and

```
nix-store --read-log
```

If the build failure cache was not already enabled, there is probably no (easy) way to recall which builds have failed, unless you have something to `grep -R` for in `/nix/var/log/nix/drvs/`.