# Is it possible to keep the test suite logs generated by Cabal when run through nix-build?

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, nix

I have a .cabal file specifying a test suite, and a default.nix file generated with `cabal2nix`.

Then I have a release.nix file (containing something like `pkgs.haskell.packages.ghc802.callPackage ./default.nix {})` that I can `nix-build`.

It works: I have a result symlink with my program.

While compiling my program with `nix-build`, I see in the output this line: `Test suite logged to: dist/test/myprogram-0.0.0-test-suite.log` (I guess produced indirectly by `cabal test`), but the file seems to be discarded.

Is it possible to keep around that log file (possibly within the directory pointed to by the result symlink) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264375/2789312 does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Keeping the log files in case the test suite was successful

You can specify a shell script which gets executed after the test suite is run by `postCheck`. This is only executed, if the test suite is successful.

Calling `cabal2nix` with or without `--shell` will contain a derivation like that in the output:

```
 { mkDerivation, base, stdenv }:
      mkDerivation {
        pname = "sample";
        version = "0.0.0.1";
        src = ./.;
        isLibrary = false;
        isExecutable = true;
        executableHaskellDepends = [ base ];
        testHaskellDepends = [ base ];
        license = stdenv.lib.licenses.unfree;
        hydraPlatforms = stdenv.lib.platforms.none;
      };
```

All you have to add is

```
 postCheck = ''
              mkdir -p $out/logs
              find dist/test -name \*log -exec cp '{}' $out/logs \;
            '';
```

and you will find your log files in `result/logs`.

The whole derivation will now look like:

```
 { mkDerivation, base, stdenv }:
      mkDerivation {
        pname = "sample";
        version = "0.0.0.1";
        src = ./.;
        isLibrary = false;
        isExecutable = true;
        executableHaskellDepends = [ base ];
        testHaskellDepends = [ base ];
        license = stdenv.lib.licenses.unfree;
        hydraPlatforms = stdenv.lib.platforms.none;
        postCheck = ''
              mkdir -p $out/logs
              find dist/test -name \*log -exec cp '{}' $out/logs \;
            '';
      };
```

## Keeping the log files in case the test suite failed

If you want to look at these log files in case the test suite fails, you can call `nix-build` with the option `--keep-failed` or `-K`. This way it will keep the temporary build directory and print a message like

```
note: keeping build directory '/tmp/nix-build-sample-0.0.0.1.drv-0'
```

near the end of its output (third to last line for me). You will find the log files in that directory. In my
example, they have been placed in

```
/tmp/nix-build-sample-0.0.0.1.drv-0/sample/dist/test
```